# WCF SOAP to WCF REST conversion in MVC giving end point error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4, rest, soap

**Problem Statement:**

Performing MVC CRUD operations using WCF Service.Everything was working fine with SOAP,but when i changed from SOAP to REST it is giving end point error.I suspect that there might be some problem with my webconfig..!!!

**Exception Details:**

```
"There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/ALCMS.MasterConfigurationService/Service1/InsertAssetType that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details."
```

WCF REST service is hosting properly and it is running.I'm getting the exception mentioned above in WCF REST Service method calls in controller like :

```
 objSvcMasterConfig.InsertAssetType(objAssetTypeDC);
 objSvcMasterConfig.UpdateAssetType(objAssetTypeDC);
 objSvcMasterConfig.DeleteAssetType(objAssetTypeDC);
```

What i'm doing wrong??

I'm having two projects in Solution

1. WCF Service library
2. MVC Razor application

**1. WCF Service Library:**

**IService1.cs**

***Data Contract:***

```
[DataContract]
    public class AssetTypeDC
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int AssetTypeID { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }

    }
```

***Service Contract:***

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        #region Asset Type
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
                 RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                 ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                 UriTemplate = "InsertAssetType")]
        bool InsertAssetType(AssetTypeDC objAssetTypeDC);

        [WebInvoke(Method = "PUT",
                 RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                 ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                 UriTemplate = "UpdateAssetType")]
        [OperationContract]
        bool UpdateAssetType(AssetTypeDC objAssetTypeDC);

        [WebInvoke(Method = "DELETE",
                 RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                 ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                 UriTemplate = "DeleteAssetType")]
        [OperationContract]
        bool DeleteAssetType(AssetTypeDC objAssetTypeDC);

        #endregion


    }
```

***Service.cs***

```
        public bool InsertAssetType(AssetTypeDC objAssetTypeDC)
        {
            try
            {
                objAssetType.ID = objAssetTypeDC.ID;
                objAssetType.AssetTypeID = objAssetTypeDC.AssetTypeID;
                objAssetType.Name = objAssetTypeDC.Name;
                dbEntity.AssetTypes.Attach(objAssetType);
                var entry = dbEntity.Entry(objAssetType);
                dbEntity.AssetTypes.Add(objAssetType);
                dbEntity.SaveChanges();
                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public bool UpdateAssetType(AssetTypeDC objAssetTypeDC)
        {
            try
            {
                objAssetTypeID = ID;
                objAssetType.AssetTypeID = objAssetTypeDC.AssetTypeID;
                objAssetType.Name = objAssetTypeDC.Name;
                dbEntity.AssetTypes.Attach(objAssetType);
                var entry = dbEntity.Entry(objAssetType);
                entry.Property(e => e.Name).IsModified = true;
                dbEntity.SaveChanges();
                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public bool DeleteAssetType(AssetTypeDC objAssetTypeDC)
        {
            try
            {
                objAssetType.AssetTypeID = objAssetTypeDC.AssetTypeID;
                objAssetType.ID = objAssetTypeDC.ID;
                dbEntity.AssetTypes.Attach(objAssetType);
                dbEntity.Entry(objAssetType).State = EntityState.Deleted;
                dbEntity.SaveChanges();
                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

***App.Config:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="ALCMS.MasterConfigurationService.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="ALCMS.MasterConfigurationService.Service1Behaviour">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/ALCMS.MasterConfigurationService/Service1/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="ALCMS.MasterConfigurationService.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="ALCMS.MasterConfigurationService.RESTEndpointBehaviour">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ALCMS.MasterConfigurationService.RESTEndpointBehaviour">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ALCMS.MasterConfigurationService.Service1Behaviour">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  </entityFramework>
<connectionStrings><add name="DB_V2Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Entities.MasterConfigurationEntity.csdl|res://*/Entities.MasterConfigurationEntity.ssdl|res://*/Entities.MasterConfigurationEntity.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=SQL-PC\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=DB_V2;user id=sa;password=Sql@123;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings></configuration>
```

**2.MVC Application**

**Controller:**

***Insert Operation:***

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(AssetTypeModel assettypemodel)
    {
         if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            objAssetTypeDC.ID = 1;
            objAssetTypeDC.AssetTypeID = assettypemodel.ID;
            objAssetTypeDC.Name = assettypemodel.Name;
            objSvcMasterConfig.InsertAssetType(objAssetTypeDC);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(assettypemodel);
    }
```

***Update Operation:***

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(AssetTypeModel assettypemodel, int id, int ID)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        objAssetTypeDC.ID = assettypemodel.ID = ID;
        objAssetTypeDC.AssetTypeID = assettypemodel.AssetTypeID = id;
        objAssetTypeDC.Name = assettypemodel.Name;
        objSvcMasterConfig.UpdateAssetType(objAssetTypeDC);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(assettypemodel);
}
```

***Delete Operation:***

```
public ActionResult Delete(int id = 0, int ID = 0)
{
    AssetTypeModel assettypemodel = db.AssetType.Find(id, ID);
    if (assettypemodel == null)
    {

        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(assettypemodel);
}
```

***Web.Config:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DB" connectionString="Data Source=SQL-PC\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=DB_V2;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=Sql@123;Pooling=False;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

    <add name="DBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Entities.WebEntity.csdl|res://*/Entities.WebEntity.ssdl|res://*/Entities.WebEntity.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=SQL\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=DB_V2;user id=sa;Password=Sql@123;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"><assemblies><add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" /></assemblies></compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Login" protection="All" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
     <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="30" stateConnectionString="tcpip=SQL-PC\SQLEXPRESS,1433" cookieless="false" regenerateExpiredSessionId="false" />
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  </entityFramework>
 <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WebHttpBinding_IService1" />
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
   <behaviors>
     <endpointBehaviors>
       <behavior name="ALCMS.MasterConfigurationService.RESTEndpointBehaviour">
         <webHttp />
       </behavior>
     </endpointBehaviors>
   </behaviors>
    <client>
     <endpoint address="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/ALCMS.MasterConfigurationService/Service1/" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WebHttpBinding_IService1" behaviorConfiguration="ALCMS.MasterConfigurationService.RESTEndpointBehaviour" contract="MasterConfigurationServiceReference.IService1" name="WebHttpBinding_IService1" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Mr Vishal,

Instead of converting, you can develop in REST only.

Comment: Actually i have developed in REST only from scrap....But I'm getting endpoint error....

Comment: Ok then there might be different issue, in config file try to give setting that should support both SOAP and REST.

I am new into this, please dont mind.